# Infinite loop in browser's console

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

Can someone explain why result of this is infinite loop??

```
var name = true;
var soloLoop = function () {
  while (name) {
     console.log(name);
     name = false;
  }
};

soloLoop();
```

- **Note 1**: Can be reproduced only in browser's console.
- **Note 2**: Is reproducible only with variable "name".

Comment: You're clashing with the global `window.name`, which can only be set to strings.

Comment: The joys of putting everything in the global scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you declare variables in the global scope, as you're doing here, they're actually contained as properties on the global object, in this case `window`.  [`window.name` is something that already exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), and can only be set to a string.

When you do:

```
var name = true;
```

It's actually setting the `window.name` to `"true"`.  Same for `name = false` - it sets it to `"false"`.  Since `"false"` is "truthy", the `while` loop will never exit.

Comment: your answer does not explain why it is reproduced only if the code is running from the browser console, in simple script the loop is executed only once

Comment: It will reproduce outside of the console too, so long as it's in the global scope.  The likes of jsfiddle etc won't be in the global scope.

Comment: true, I was testing in the jsfiddle and Node environment :P